# Copying a file using Cordova

Tags: cordova, fileapi

I've been trying to copy file named versions.txt from applicationDirectory to externalApplicationStorageDirectory using cordova but code fails.

here is the code

```
var path = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/Data/versions.txt";

      window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path,
      function gotFile(fileEntry)
      {

          window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
              function onSuccess(fileSystem)
              { 
                      var directory = new DirectoryEntry("versions.txt", path);

                      fileEntry.copyTo(directory, 'versions.txt',
                          function()
                          {
                              alert('copying was successful')
                          },
                          function()
                          {
                              alert('unsuccessful copying')
                          });

              }, null);
      },null);
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

The fileEntry.copyTo somehow always gave error, so I tried the fileEntry.moveTo as below, which works well for me in copying any file from the www into say the Library folder of the iOS device.

```
function copyToLocation(fileName){       
console.log("Copying :"+fileName);
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory+"www/"+fileName,function (fileEntry)
    {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory,function (directory)
        {                  
           fileEntry.moveTo(directory, 'new_fileName.txt',function(){
                alert('Successful Copy!');
            },
            function()
            {
                alert('Copying Unsuccessful ');
            });
        },null);
    }, null);
 }
```

Comment: it's a mess. why your function `function copyToLocation(fileName)` has only one parameter? Could you kindly clarify and rewrite? Namely `function copyFile(dirOrigin, fileNameOrigin, dirDest, fileNameDest)` Thanks

Comment: It works perfectly. In this particular case, the source & destination is already known i.e from applicationDirectory to dataDirectory and the code is only to explain how to copy the file. Its up to you how you want the function signature - doesn't have to be called a mess!

Answer (score 3):

I finally got a functioning broader no specific/case function to copy a file having a `baseFileURI` to a temporary (`fileSystem == LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY`) or persistent (`fileSystem == LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT`) APP directory, the destiny file having the name `destPathName`.

It uses the [`cordova-plugin-file`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/) plugin.

```js
function copyFile(baseFileURI, destPathName, fileSystem){
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(baseFileURI, 
        function(file){        
            window.requestFileSystem(fileSystem, 0, 
                function (fileSystem) {
                    var documentsPath = fileSystem.root;
                    console.log(documentsPath);
                    file.copyTo(documentsPath, destPathName,
                    function(res){                        
                        console.log('copying was successful to: ' + res.nativeURL)
                    }, 
                    function(){
                        console.log('unsuccessful copying')
                    });
                });
        }, 
        function(){
            console.log('failure! file was not found')
        });
}
```

Use this function, for example, like this

```
copyFile("file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.form.parking.violation/cache/IMG-20180505-WA0004.jpg",         
        "myImg.jpg",
        LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY);
```

Comment: This approach worked in my case. The other approach returned INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR

Answer (score 2):

now it works, target directory should be resolved.

here is the solution

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory,
                      function onSuccess(dirEntry)
                      {
                          //alert(JSON.stringify(dirEntry));

                          fileEntry.copyTo(dirEntry, 'versions.txt',
                              function()
                              {
                                  alert('copying was successful')
                              },
                              function()
                              {
                                  alert('unsuccessful copying')
                              });
                      }, null);
```

Comment: where does it come `fileEntry`?

Answer (score 1):

Served my source code to the PhoneGap developer app. My file copy code is below.

```js
   //COPY FILE
   var wwwDirEntry;

   //resolve url for directory entry for putting in copied file
   window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory+'phonegapdevapp/www/', function success(dirEntry) {
       wwwDirEntry = dirEntry;
   });

   //resolve file URL to file entry to enable copying
   //
   //Desired URL: file:///data/user/0/com.adobe.phonegap.app/files/phonegapdevapp/www/my_awesome_file.doc
   //BASE URL: cordova.file.dataDirectory / file:///data/user/0/com.adobe.phonegap.app/files/
   //
   //alert(JSON.stringify(cordova.file.dataDirectory));
   //
   window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory+'phonegapdevapp/www/my_awesome_file.doc',
      function onSuccess(fileEntry)
      {
          //alert(JSON.stringify(fileEntry));
          fileEntry.copyTo(wwwDirEntry, 'a_copy_of_my_awesome_file.doc',
          function()
          {
              alert('copying was successful');
          },
          function()
          {
              alert('copying FAILED');
          });
     }, function (e) { alert(JSON.stringify(e)); });
```