# How to copy a file to another directory in Cordova?

Tags: cordova

I had write code for  copy file to one Location to anothor Location.but it throws unknown error.and also am facing nullPointerException when running in andriod.can anyone explain me please.
Here my code below

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, successCallback, errorCallback)
                    function successCallback(filesystem) {
                        alert("2");
                        filesystem.root.getDirectory('mservice', {create:false}, function(fileEntry) {alert("3");
                            fileEntry.getFile('queue_mgr.txt',{create:false},function(file){alert("4");
                            var filePath = "/Download/queue_mgr.txt";
                            alert(filePath);
                            var name ='queue_mgr.txt';
                            parentEntry =new DirectoryEntry(name,filePath);
                            //alert(parentEntry.name);
                            alert(parentEntry);
                                file.copyTo(parentEntry,'queue_mgr.txt',function(e){alert("success"+e.fullPath);},function(er){alert("fail"+er.code);});
                            },errorCallback);
                        },errorCallback);
                    }
                    function errorCallback(error) {
                        alert("ERROR: " + error.code);
                    }
```

--

```
System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.transferTo(FileUtils.java:784)
11-14 21:41:29.785 32161-32229/com.example.database W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.access$1300(FileUtils.java:56)
11-14 21:41:29.785 32161-32229/com.example.database W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$21.run(FileUtils.java:510)
11-14 21:41:29.785 32161-32229/com.example.database W/System.err:     at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$25.run(FileUtils.java:657)
11-14 21:41:29.785 32161-32229/com.example.database W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-14 21:41:29.785 32161-32229/com.example.database W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-14 21:41:29.795 32161-32229/com.example.database W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying a file using Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548292/copying-a-file-using-cordova)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the source: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/src/android/FileUtils.java

It looks like you're hitting around the FileNotFoundException? It might be easier to tell what call exactly it's failing on by adding some more exception handling to your code.

---

EDIT: The exception is coming from an internal method `TransferTo()`, which is called from `file.copyTo()` at around line 515. The method is looking for a couple values, one or more of which appear to be empty -- hence your exception:

```
    if (srcURLstr == null || destURLstr == null) {
        // either no source or no destination provided
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }
```

Check to make sure the source and destination params passed into `file.copyTo()` are valid URL strings and not empty.

Comment: i can't get any clarifications.plz help me out of this.i have searched a lot.but i didn't get any success