# Copying a file into internal storage in Cordova

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a Cordova mobile app and I'm implementing an import feature. The user is expected to place a file `clients.db` in the `Documents` folder, launch the import function from the app and the app itself should copy this file from the current location to the internal database storage, ready to be opened as a SQLite database

Here my code:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + "/Documents/clients.db", function(fs) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL("file://data/data/com.app.clients/databases/",function(directoryEntry) {
       fs.copyTo(directoryEntry, "clients.db", function() {
          //done
       }, function(err) {
          //here I get err = 1
       });
    }, function(){
        //err
    });
}, function(){
    //err
});
```

The file `clients.db` is in the `Documents` folder but when I launch the code the `copyTo` function fails returning err = 1 which means file not found.

While debugging I noticed that the variable `fs` is valorized correctly:

```
filesystem : FileSystem fullPath : "/Documents/clients.db" isDirectory : false isFile : true name : "clients.db" nativeURL : "file:///storage/emulated/0/Documents/clients.db"
__proto__ : Entry
```

`directoryEntry` is valorized correclty too and it's recognized as a directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the url match the folder path? It looks strange.

Comment: you mean file:///data/data/com.app.clients/databases/ ?? why does it look strange?

Comment: one is to resolve the origin, the other to resolve the destination. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: sry didnt seen that u use fs. look that u can read the file and write something to destination folder

Comment: what do you mean by using the root path from any cordova function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548292/copying-a-file-using-cordova perhaps this can helping you

Answer (score 0):

Refer my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49146017/7707069).
The from location should be in the 1st resolveLocalFileSystemURL call & the to location in the 2nd.